# Show Stimulsoft Reports in ASP.NET web page

Tags: stimulsoft

I want to show reports generated using stimulsoft in a ASP.NET webpage. I have loaded the report and registered the datasource related to the report using the following code. But I am having issues with displaying it in a web page. What should I do to display this in a web page.

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
report.Load("D:/Work/AllClassifieds/DevSourceBranch/WebSolution/Website/Reports/Price Sensitivity/PriceSensitivity.mrt");
report.RegData("PriceSensitivityData", ds);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put StiWebViewer or StiWebViewerFx on the ASPX page and pass the report to it with next code:

```
StiWebViewer1.Report = report;
```